# install python3 + lxml on windows

Tags: python, windows, windows-7, python-3.x, lxml

I would like to install python3 with lxml on windows 7.
There seems to be several versions available.
What's the best version/way to install?

- By best I mostly mean the easiest.
- Points if I don't have to compile anything.

Comment: Try python-3.2.2.msi from http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.2.2/ and lxml-2.3.1.win32-py3.2.exe from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the current stable version of 3, 3.2.2.  You can find a windows installer here http://python.org/ftp/python/3.2.2/python-3.2.2.msi that will install python for you.

Use the Python Package Index version of lxml: it has a windows installer specifically for Python 3.

http://pypi.python.org/packages/3.1/l/lxml/lxml-2.2.8.win32-py3.1.exe#md5=d1fb73a8596bb77e155cef7ae6b0bc53

Download and run the Python installer then download and run the lxml installer: it should be that easy.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem locating the correct version.  After several hours of confusion I finally found the windows binary for Python 3 at Christoph Gohlke's [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) website at UC, Irvine.

He truly has the A-Z of Python extensions, as long as it's available for Python.  Anything one could want from the PIP installer to Chinese word segmentation, to a multi-taper Fourier spectral estimator.  Beyond that it gets into biologic & scientific specialty extensions.

Answer (score 1):

### No compilations and IMHO, the best way:

Mainly because the instructions below the most complete **and** still FAST to complete.  On more than one occasions, using just the MSI and the LXML binaries, I've run into issues with the install breaking/getting `gcc` and `mingw` errors.

---

**These instructions are for Windows7 or Windows8 with Python3.3**.

**However**, they should work for various versions as the releases of python and other respective prerequisites change/evolve:

1. Install ***Python3.3***:

   1. Download the last release of Python3.3 (currently 3.3.5) from the downloads page [HERE](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-335/)

      - Direct link for Win32 MSI installer -> [HERE](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.5/python-3.3.5.msi)
      - Direct link for Win64 MSI installer -> [HERE](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.5/python-3.3.5.amd64.msi)
   2. Simply run the MSI to install python.  It will register itself in the registry, and appear in Add/REmove Programs.
   3. **NOTE:** my instructions that follow assume that you choose to install python to the default path of `C:\python33\` when asked during the Python Installation Wizard
2. Add the `C:\python33\` and `C:\python33\scripts` folders to the system path by adding those directories to the `PATH` environment variable from the **Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings link (Advanced Tab) > Environmental Variables (Button)**.
3. (OPTIONAL) Install ***OpenSSL***:

   1. Download **Win32 OpenSSL page** from [HERE](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) for your version of Windows and PC architecture
   2. Download **Visual C++ 2008 redistributables** for your version of Windows and PC architecture
   3. Download **OpenSSL** for your version of Windows and architecture (the regular version, not the light one)
   4. Add the following (depending on your architecture) directory (or wherever you insalled to) to your `PATH`, the same way you added `C:\python33` and `C:\python33\scripts` above:

      - **32-bit:**  `c:\openssl-win32\bin`
      - **64-bit:**  `c:\openssl-win64\bin`
4. Install ***Setuptools*** (`get-pip.py` should install Setuptools for you), but, just in case...

   1. Download `ez_setup.py` [HERE](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py) and save it in `C:\python33\scripts`
   2. Run **`C:\python33\scripts> python ez_setup.py`**
5. Install ***PIP***

   1. Download `get-pip.py` from [HERE](https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py) and save it in `C:\python33\scripts`
   2. Run **`C:\python33\scripts> python get-pip.py`**
6. Install ***LXML***

   1. Download `LXML 3.3.3` from [HERE](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.3.3) for your version of Windows and PC architecture
   2. Run the EXE file

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of lxml (3.6.0) now supports the Wheel format, so there is no problem with installing it with pip:

```
pip install lxml
```

Comment: May I ask a question? Which OS are you running? Windows or Linux?

Comment: This worked for me on Windows and Linux. Are you having any issues?

Answer (score 0):

Worth noting that Python3 is only supported on Windows 7 up to version 3.8.6 - beyond that it fails to install with an error similar to the following in the Python log file:

```
[2490:291C][2020-11-14T14:22:21]e000: Windows 8.1 or later is required to continue installation
```

This is mentioned in the [Python Releases for Windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) download page:

> Note that Python 3.9.0 cannot be used on Windows 7 or earlier.
>
> [...]
>
> Note that Python 3.8.6 cannot be used on Windows XP or earlier.

Hence if installing with Chocolatey, the following command is needed:

```
choco install python3 --version 3.8.6
```